# Looking for a good git workflow for new projects with a small team

Tags: git, version-control

I work in a small team of developers (there are 3 of us).
in the research that I have done, the workflow that most teams seem to follow seems to be as follows a branch is created for a feature and then the branch is merged into master when coding on the feature is complete.

That seems to work well with mature projects where most of the code is already in place and a feature that one person work is separate from another, but with a new project developer really need to see each others changes as they are made and much of the work that needs to be done initially is "laying the foundations".

Whilst during the initial development, developer may work on specific features, other developers may want to see them before they are completely finished, and initially whether they are finished or not may not be well defined as a feature may be revisited several times in between working on other features.

Are there any established patterns on how to manage the git workflow in this case? Would it make more sense for us to all work on the same branch and call it something like "initial_implementation" and then merge it into master when it reaches a reasonable level of maturity, and start working on feature branches?

Comment: Lock the main branch (usually `master`) so force pushes are rejected. Then create and merge other branches as you like.

Comment: Can you be a bit a more specific how about how the merging might be managed? For example would you recommend having a "develop" branch which everyone pushes to in the initial stages or perhaps having everyone work in their own branch and merging into the develop branch periodically, then merging develop back into their own branch to get other peoples changes?

Comment: The most intuitive way. For every feature/project you create a new branch and when it's done, merge into the main branch. For small/quick changes, push directly.

Comment: OK,  but you may need to come back to a feature - say you implement a feature in a branch and the merge it so that other people can see it. Then you realize something more needs to be done on that feature - do create a new branch from the main one or do you merge the main branch back into your feature branch and then continue developing?

Comment: Both are OK. Pick the flavor you like.